# Asp.Net CheckBoxList ListItem CssClass Override by aspNetDisabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a CheckBoxList on WebFrom

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="chkList" runat="server">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

now the Control is populated on server side some thing like this

```
DataTable dt = myDatasource

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   ListItem li = new ListItem();
   li.Attributes.Add("class", (string)dr["CssClass"]);
   //........ Some More Properties.....

   chkList.Items.Add(li);
}
```

after this i need to disable the some checkboxes on basis of some condition

```
foreach(ListItem item in chkList.Items)
{
   if (// Some Condition)
   {
     item.Enabled = false;
   }
}
```

now the issue is when item.Enabled = false the class attribute is override by

```
class = "aspNetDisabled";
```

and the class that is applied at the time of populating no more.

i need that class to do some processing in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. In my case on disabled elements was applied that aspNetDisabled class and all disabled controls had wrong colors. So, I used jquery to remove this class on every element/control I wont and everything works and looks great now.

This is my code for removing aspNetDisabled class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("span").removeClass("aspNetDisabled");
    $("select").removeClass("aspNetDisabled");
    $("input").removeClass("aspNetDisabled");

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your class using **CssClass** instead of **class**.

I'm using **.NET 4.5.1**.

I've tested this and it appears that if you have the class attribute set, `.enabled = false` will *overwrite* the class property with **aspNetDisabled**. However, if you have the **CssClass** set, that value will be *merged* with **aspNetDisabled**.

Note: I see you are setting class with this line of code:

```
li.Attributes.Add("class", (string)dr["CssClass"]);
```

However, I should note that I'm seeing the same behavior when I have **class** set instead of **CssClass** in the markup.